# Laravel 5.2 w/ Yajra datatables, in the Read view of an object, how might I display all the datatables for the hasMany children of the parent Model?

Tags: php, laravel-5, has-many, yajra-datatable

The parent model is Fiefdom, and the hasMany child model is Fief (but can and will include more, later).  When navigating to /fiefdoms/x, I'd like the display to include, after the fiefdom-specific fields, a series of datatables for the child model(s), one for each hasMany relationship.

I've got datatables working just fine in isolation (fief index), but I'm a bit confused on how to load them into pages that aren't dedicated to a single datatable.  Some relevant code snippets I'm using...

FiefController.php (index)

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the Fief.
 *
 * @param FiefDataTable $fiefDataTable
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(FiefDataTable $fiefDataTable)
{
    return $fiefDataTable->render('fiefs.index');
}
```

FiefdomController.php (show)

```
/**
 * Display the specified Fiefdom.
 *
 * @param  int $id
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $fiefdom = $this->fiefdomRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($fiefdom)) {
        Flash::error('Fiefdom not found');

        return redirect(route('fiefdoms.index'));
    }

    return view('fiefdoms.show')
        ->with('fiefdom', $fiefdom);
}
```

fiefDataTable.php

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Fief;
use Form;
use Yajra\Datatables\Services\DataTable;

class FiefDataTable extends DataTable
{

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function ajax()
    {
        return $this->datatables
            ->eloquent($this->query())
            ->addColumn('action', 'fiefs.datatables_actions')
            ->make(true);
    }

    /**
     * Get the query object to be processed by datatables.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query()
    {
        $fiefs = Fief::query();

        return $this->applyScopes($fiefs);
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\Datatables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->addAction(['width' => '10%'])
            ->ajax('')
            ->parameters([
                'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
                'scrollX' => false,
                'buttons' => [
                    'print',
                    'reset',
                    'reload',
                    [
                         'extend'  => 'collection',
                         'text'    => '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export',
                         'buttons' => [
                             'csv',
                             'excel',
                             'pdf',
                         ],
                    ],
                    'colvis'
                ]
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['name' => 'name', 'data' => 'name'],
            'territory_id' => ['name' => 'territory_id', 'data' => 'territory_id'],
            'fiefdom_id' => ['name' => 'fiefdom_id', 'data' => 'fiefdom_id'],
            'fiefdom_type' => ['name' => 'fiefdom_type', 'data' => 'fiefdom_type'],
            'ruler_id' => ['name' => 'ruler_id', 'data' => 'ruler_id'],
            'ruler_type' => ['name' => 'ruler_type', 'data' => 'ruler_type'],
            'steward_id' => ['name' => 'steward_id', 'data' => 'steward_id'],
            'steward_type' => ['name' => 'steward_type', 'data' => 'steward_type']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'fiefs';
    }
}
```

fiefdom/fields.blade.php (referenced in 'fiefdoms.show') includes:

```
//various fiefdom fields, and then:
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <h2>Fiefs</h2>
    @include('fiefs.table')
</div>
```

fiefs/index.blade.php

```
//usual container stuff, then

<div class="box-body">
    @include('fiefs.table')
</div>
```

fiefs/table.blade.php

```
@section('css')
    @include('layouts.datatables_css')
@endsection

{!! $dataTable->table(['width' => '100%']) !!}

@section('scripts')
    @include('layouts.datatables_js') //various js includes
    {!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
@endsection
```

The index datatable for /fiefs shows up just fine, but it's not working in /fiefdoms/x.  The problem, of course, is there's no datatable info being sent to the view ($dataTable is undefined).  Should I build and send that in the controller, or have it load up via ajax somehow?  The html builder stuff, maybe?  What is the easiest method to accomplishing this task, keeping in mind I'll need to include multiple datatables?  Am I going the wrong way here, or can I just send dataTable info to the view?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the html builder function found in the related datatable.

XController

```
use App\DataTables\YDataTable;

...

    public function show($id, YDataTable $yDataTable)
    {
        $dataTable = $yDataTable
            ->html()
            ->ajax([
                'url' => route('y.index'),
                'type' => 'GET',
                'data' => 'function(d) { d.key = "value"; }',
            ]);
        return view('whatever', compact('dataTable'));
    }
```

XView

```
@include('y.table')
```

Most of the datatable stuff is set up with the html() function, and the data source is defined by the ajax() function.  You can filter and whatnot from there.